# How to iterate through map and push keys with similar values into the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I've got javascript map with structure like this:

```
let map = {3 => 1,
           15 => 2,
           0 => 2,
           8 => 3,
           9 => 3}
```

I need to receive the arrays of keys, and keys with similar values should be in the same array.

```
[[3], [15,0],[8,9]]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
    let answers = [];
    let currentVal = 1;
    map.forEach((value, key)=>{
      let subArr = [];
      if(value === currentVal){
        subArr.push(key);
        answers.push(subArr);
        currentVal++;
   }

    });
    
    return answers;
```

And it returns `[[3], [15], [8]]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your map is an object, not map for readability reasons, but if u are using Map there you can change methods to get elements but main idea you can see below:

```js
const data = {
  3: 1,
  15: 2,
  0: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 3
};

const customData = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (value in acc) {
    acc[value].push(key);
  } else {
    acc[value] = [key];
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const finalArray = Object.values(customData);
console.log(finalArray);
```

Edit with `Map()` example:

```
const data = new Map([
  [3, 1],
  [15, 2],
  [0, 2],
  [8, 3],
  [9, 3]
]);

const customData = Array.from(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (value in acc) {
    acc[value].push(key);
  } else {
    acc[value] = [key];
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const finalArray = Object.values(customData);
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: It's a Map instance, like let map = new Map();

Comment: Sorry, thought it's only problem with converting structure, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and *destructuring* `key, value` but I change their place as `value, key` to match the data structure map provided by OP :

```js
let map = { 3: 1, 15: 2, 0: 2, 8: 3, 9: 3 };
const arr = [];
for (const [value, key] of Object.entries(map)) {
  if (arr[key]) {
    arr[key].push(value);
  } else {
    arr[key] = [value];
  }
}
console.log(arr.filter(Boolean)); // [[3], [15,0],[8,9]]
```

**NOTE** `arr.filter(Boolean)` to remove falsy (empty) values from array since index *0* have no array inside of it!

Answer (score 0):

Your map is not a valid one. Hence, I am creating it by using `Map` instance. You can have a look in this official documentation of [`Map Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Creating a map object by using Map instance
const map = new Map();

// Setting the key, values in map object.
map.set(3, 1)
map.set(15, 2)
map.set(0, 2)
map.set(8, 3)
map.set(9, 3)

// Declaring an empty array which will store the result.
const arr = [];

// Iterate over a map object and assign the keys of map object into an 'arr'.
for (const [key, value] of map) {
  (arr[value]) ? arr[value].push(key) : arr[value] = [key];
}

// Output
console.log(arr.filter(Boolean));
```